# KafkaListener ConsumerConfig AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_DOC earliest for multiple listeners

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, listener, consumer

I have 3 listeners in my spring boot application. Only one listener should read topic from beginning. If I add to the yml file: `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset: earliest` then it works for all listeners, but I need it only for one. I have added:

```
import static org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_DOC;
......
@KafkaListener(groupId = "${random.uuid}",
            properties = {AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_DOC + ":earliest"})
```

But it did not work, settings was not picked up as I see printed settings on a launch:

```
ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are providing wrong config it should be `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` not `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_DOC`

```
@KafkaListener(groupId = "${random.uuid}",
        properties = {AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG + ":earliest"})
```

or you can specify the property directly

```
@KafkaListener(groupId = "${random.uuid}",
        properties = {"auto.offset.reset = earliest"})
```

From doc [@KafkaListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html) annotation there is a field called `properties` which accepts String array

> Kafka consumer properties; they will supersede any properties with the same name defined in the consumer factory (if the consumer factory supports property overrides).

**Supported Syntax**

> The supported syntax for key-value pairs is the same as the syntax defined for entries in a Java properties file:

```
key=value
key:value
key value
```

> group.id and client.id are ignored.